# CSS Change links color on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, hover

I have the following CSS section with both normal text and some weblinks. I need to put links changing color on mouse hover at the paragraph section. How can I do it?

I've tried with:

```
        ul.contact li p:hover a {
        color: #eb050183;
    }
```

My CSS

```
ul.contact li {
    position: relative;
    border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
    padding: 1.3em 0 1.3em 7em;
}

    ul.contact li h3 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 1.3em;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    ul.contact li p {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }

    ul.contact li:first-child {
        padding-top: 0;
        border-top: 0;
    }

        ul.contact li:first-child h3 {
            top: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Your code is not working simply because you've missed a space after `ul`. it should be `ul .contact li p:hover a`

Answer (score 2):

To change color of anchor link on hover you need to set CSS as follows:

```
 ul.contact li p a:hover {
        color: #eb050183;
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the link color by hovering `p` , not by hovering the link itself

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed `text-decoration:none;` for your anchor tag. Add this along with color property. Also put hover with `a`
a:hover{color:#FF00FF}